# Zigbee Address in JAVA

Tags: java, zigbee

I am using Java XBEE API with Zigbee modules to send data to remote zigbee. I am using 64 bit address of remote zigbee module like this:

```
XBeeAddress64 destination = new XBeeAddress64(0x00, 0x13,0xa2,0x00,0x40,0xa9,0xd0,0xd1);
```

It works fine but I don't have any idea what `0x00` means in JAVA whether it is hex, integer or string. I have a string containing remote address and i want to use this as remote address like this:

```
address_64 = "0x00 0x13 0xa2 0x00 0x40 0xa9 0xd0 0xd1";
destination = new XBeeAddress64(address_64);
```

But this time it gives error. Does anyone know hoe to solve it?

Comment: According [to the documentation](http://xbee-api.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/com/rapplogic/xbee/api/XBeeAddress64.html#XBeeAddress64(java.lang.String)) this is possible when you omit the `0x` in the address.

Comment: Thank you Gerald! You have solved my problem

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://xbee-api.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/com/rapplogic/xbee/api/XBeeAddress64.html#XBeeAddress64%28java.lang.String%29)  this is possible when you omit the 0x in the address.

Your address string should then look like this:

```
String address_64 = "00 13 a2 00 40 a9 d0 d1";
destination = new XBeeAddress64(address_64);
```